# Two Navigation Menus in Themes Produce the same menus?

Tags: themes, navigation, admin-menu

Alright so I've got two navigation menus that I've registered with my theme:

```
<?php

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar();

add_theme_support( 'menus' );

if ( function_exists('register_nav_menu') ) {
    register_nav_menu( 'primary_nav', 'Primary Navigation');
    register_nav_menu( 'secondary_nav', 'Secondary Navigation');
}

?>
```

### **Functions.php**

And then Beyond that I've got two places in my header where I display the navigation menus:

```
                <!-- BEGIN: Navigation Menu primary_nav (Primary Navigation) -->
                <?php
                  if(function_exists('wp_nav_menu'))
                  {
                    wp_nav_menu(
                        array(
                            'menu' => 'primary_nav',
                            'container' => '',
                            'depth' => 1,
                            'menu_id' => 'menu'
                        )
                    );
                  }
                  else 
                  {
                ?>
                   <ul>
                    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1'); ?>
                   </ul>
                <?php
                  }
                ?>
                <!-- END: Navigation Menu primary_nav (Primary Navigation) -->
            </div>
```

**header.php** - Location 1

```
        <!-- BEGIN: Secondary Navigation Menu -->
        <?php 
              if(function_exists('wp_nav_menu')) {
                wp_nav_menu(
                    array(
                        'menu' => 'secondary_nav',
                        'container' => '',
                        'depth' => 1,
                        'menu_id' => 'secondary_nav_id'
                    )
                );
              }
              else {
        ?>

            <ul>
                <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1'); ?>
            </ul>
        <?php
              }
        ?>
        <!-- END: Secondary Navigation Menu -->
```

**header.php** - Location 2

In the admin page for the theme everything shows up just fine, both menus appear in the list both Primary Navigation and Secondary Navigation.

And from the admin screen I've added two distinct sets of menu items.  However, whenever I load up my theme, for some reason I end up with only the menus from the Primary Navigation appearing twice.

Is there something I've forgotten that would cause this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `theme_location` instead of `menu` in arguments. Too late here to look up specifics, but I remember documentation/code being absolutely confusing about that.

Comment: Yes, for whatever odd reason that did fix the problem...thanks!

Comment: Yep; you need to use the `theme_location` argument, which is what your arguments in `register_nav_menu()` define. What's happening is that `wp_nav_menu()` is looking for a menu that is *named* "primary_nav" and "secondary_nav". Since neither exists, both calls to `wp_nav_menu()` are falling back to the default, `wp_page_menu()` output.

Comment: I was reading a book on it actually, it must be out of date.  For anyone whose interested, here is the relevant documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: Might be helpful to name that book...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rarst's and Chip's answers above, register_nav_menu is used in this in manner:
`register_nav_menu( $location, $description )`

What you've specified as primary_nav and secondary_nav are actually menu location identifiers and not the actual menu identifiers.

That is why you have to use `theme_location` in your wp_nav_menu arguments instead of `menu`