# Two Navigation Menus - secondary nav is including main nav

Tags: themes, customization, navigation, sub-menu

[Two Navigation Menus in Themes Produce the same menus?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14614/two-navigation-menus-in-themes-produce-the-same-menus)

reference the subject on page link above. i created two navs, yet the secondary nav includes all pages. the main nav is fine, but the secondary nav is including the main nav pages as well.

the two menus contain only the pages i want per nav (appearance > menus). any suggestions?

it is my own theme built from 2010. it is located here > http://journeymaninc.ca/

at a loss at this point.

thanks kindly

Neil

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two Navigation Menus in Themes Produce the same menus?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14614/two-navigation-menus-in-themes-produce-the-same-menus)

Answer (score 0):

In your theme's functions.php did you register a new WP Menu ? 
by using a code like this:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Navigation', 'twentyten' ),
    ) );
```

And after that in your theme's header.php under `<div id="access" role="navigation">` you should add

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header-secondary', 'theme_location' => 'secondary' ) ); ?>
```